# CNContactStore.requestAccessForEntityType argument issue

Tags: swift

I am trying to get authorisation to use the addressbook using the `CNContactStore` function `requestAccessForEntityType` but I get an error I don't understand.

The function is defined in the class as:

```
public func requestAccessForEntityType(entityType: CNEntityType, completionHandler: (Bool, NSError?) -> Void)
```

This is my code:

```
let addressBookRef: CNContactStore = CNContactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler: authorizationHandler)

func authorizationHandler(granted: Bool, error: NSError?) {

}
```

Compiler error:

> Extra argument 'completionHandler' in call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I was defining the property directly in the class. Obviously you can't run a function there and so it was not working. Duh!

All I need to do was put in the class:

```
let addressBookRef = CNContactStore()
```

And the following when it was time to actually ask for permission:

```
addressBookRef.requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler: authorizationHandler)
```